# How do I pass a CLI argument to a Cucumber Java test suit?

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I have a test suite that test my web service, I want to sent a custom IP as a CLI argument from maven to the test suite so instead of having a hard-coded IP like in the example below:

```
@Before
public void server_connection() {
    ConnectionToServer serverConnection = new ConnectionToServer("localhost", 5776);
    serverConnection.open();
}
```

I want to have a variable IP like this:

```
@Before
public void server_connection() {
    ConnectionToServer serverConnection = new ConnectionToServer(IPArgumentFromMaven, 5776);
    serverConnection.open();
}
```

Comment: You can probably do this by setting a system property - been a while since I used Maven, but https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html might help. Then you can use System.getProperty(...) in your Java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your method, you can read this value as a system property like this:

```
@Before
public void server_connection() {
    ConnectionToServer serverConnection = new ConnectionToServer(System.getProperty("IPArgumentFromMaven"), 5776);
    serverConnection.open();
}
```

Now you can pass a value for IPArgumentFromMaven to maven from command line like this:

`mvn clean test -DIPArgumentFromMaven=localhost`

Comment: I using this answer as solution. Thanks